# GPG error with Zookeeper distro: Public key obsolete?

Tags: encryption, gnupg

Please consider the following output:

```
+ gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key C823E3E5B12AF29C67F81976F5CECB3CB5E9BD2D
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp.ZIIl4D5e52/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp.ZIIl4D5e52/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key B5E9BD2D from hkp server ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: /tmp/tmp.ZIIl4D5e52/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key B5E9BD2D: public key "Rakesh Radhakrishnan (CODE SIGNING KEY) <rakeshr@apache.org>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
+ gpg --batch --verify zookeeper-3.4.11.tar.gz.asc zookeeper-3.4.11.tar.gz
gpg: Signature made Wed Nov  1 18:56:29 2017 UTC using DSA key ID 68E327C1
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
```

Does it say, I have the key ID `B5E9BD2D`, but what is required is key ID `68E327C1`?

What to do?

Comment: UPD: looks like the newer release have been signed by another person; see https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/zookeeper/KEYS. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the newer release have been signed by another person; see dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/zookeeper/KEYS. Now it works.